# In a linear time invariant system, is it possible for a SS response to exist, when we have a bounded input?

Tags: signal, signal-processing, homework

The answers provided showed that it is possible. I don't understand why. I think since it said that the input signal is bounded, it means that the modes of the signal are within the unit circle, so the forced response will decay to 0. Since we dont have the forced response, there won't be a steady state. Where am I wrong here?

I read it on page 3.29 of this file . It said: "If all of the input signal poles are within the unit circle, then the forced response will decay towards zero as n → ∞."

Comment: If there is an input signal present, why would there not be a forced response?

Comment: @ThePhoton I think I'm wrong, but I thought if the modes of the signal are within the unit circle, then the forced response will decay to 0. So you're saying it IS possible to have a steady-state response?

Comment: Since you talk about the unit circle, can I assume you're asking about a discrete time system? And doing analysis in the z-domain?

Comment: Where did you read that the forced response decays to zero? I would it expect to see the transient response decaying to zero, and the forced response leading to a steady-state output (assuming a steady-state input).

Comment: @ThePhoton I read it on page 3.29 of this file <https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~fessler/course/451/l/pdf/c3.pdf>. It said: "If all of the input signal poles are within the unit circle, then the forced response will decay towards zero as n → ∞." Am I not understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't do z-transforms in my sleep, but if I read the next two bullet points in the text you referred to, they say

> - If the input signal has a pole on the unit circle then there is a persistent sinusoidal component of the input signal. The forced response to such a sinusoid is also a persistent sinusoid
> - In this case, the forced response is also called the **steady-state** response.

From this I can deduce that

1. An input with a pole on the unit circle is also a bounded input in the time domain (because the sinusoids are bounded functions). So it's not correct that all poles must be within the unit circle for the input to be bounded.
2. The text defines the steady state response as the response to an input with a pole **on** the unit circle, not the response to an input with all poles **within** the unit circle. That is, it defines the steady state response as the response to an input with a sinusoidal component, not the response to an input that decays as \$t\to\infty\$.

Comment: I just noticed on page 3.33 of the same file, it said "A causal LTI system is BIBO stable iff all of the poles of its system function are inside the unit circle." It also had an example stating "causal but pole at z = 1 so unstable".

Comment: Yes, that's about the poles of the system transfer function. Up to now we've been talking about poles of the input signal.